# problema encadenando promesas

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tomando el curso de udemy [Node: De cero a experto ( Edición 2021 )](https://udemy.com/course/node-de-cero-a-experto/learn/lecture/9465150) y al tratar de poner pronmesas en cadena obtengo que el id no existe a pesar de que si existe.

Mi código:

```js
const empleados = [
    {
        id: 1,
        nombre: 'Fernando'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        nombre: 'Linda'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        nombre: 'Karen'
    }
];

const salarios = [
    {
        id: 1,
        salario: 1000
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        salario: 1500
    }
];

let getEmpleado = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const empleado = empleados.find(emp => emp.id === id)?.nombre
        empleado ?
            resolve(empleado)
            :
            reject(`no existe empleado con el id ${id}`)
            ;
    });
}

let getSalario = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const salario = salarios.find(salary => salary.id === id)?.salario;
        salario ?
            resolve(salario)
            :
            reject(`no existe el salario para el id ${id}`);
    })
}

let id = 1;

getEmpleado(id)
    .then(empleado => console.log(empleado))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

getSalario(id)
    .then(salario => console.log(salario))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

getEmpleado(id)
    .then(empleado => getSalario(id))
    .then(salario => console.log(`El empleado ${empleado} recibe un salario de ${salario}`))
    .catch(err => console.log(`No existe el usuario con el id ${id}`))
```

Yo esperaba que me dijera

> El empleado Fernando recibe un salario de 1000

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que el empleado se está perdiendo en el scope del primer then. Lo que estás retornando es lo que devuelve la función `getSalario` que es un entero. Si no estoy mal el error que debería mostrar en el stack es de variable no asignada. Entonces debes hacer algo para mantener el valor del nombre, en el caso del vídeo lo que hace es crear una variable con un scope similar al de `id`. De este modo puedes retener el valor del primer retorno y utilizarlo en el siguiente bloque.

```js
const empleados = [
{
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'Fernando'
},
{
    id: 2,
    nombre: 'Linda'
},
{
    id: 3,
    nombre: 'Karen'
}
];

const salarios = [
{
    id: 1,
    salario: 1000
},
{
    id: 2,
    salario: 1500
}
];

let getEmpleado = (id) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const empleado = empleados.find(emp => emp.id === id)?.nombre
    empleado ?
        resolve(empleado)
        :
        reject(`no existe empleado con el id ${id}`)
        ;
});
}

let getSalario = (id) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const salario = salarios.find(salary => salary.id === id)?.salario;
    salario ?
        resolve(salario)
        :
        reject(`no existe el salario para el id ${id}`);
})
}

let id = 1;
let nombre;

getEmpleado(id)
.then(empleado => {
  nombre = empleado;
  return getSalario(id);
})
.then(salario => console.log(`El empleado ${nombre} recibe un salario de ${salario}`))
.catch(err => console.log(`No existe el usuario con el id ${id}`))
```